# text alignment issue in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Unfortunately, each line of my JSP file in eclipse luna is split into many lines like below.  It's difficult to adjust them manually. Please suggest me whether any option in eclipse that will adjust all the lines in my JSP file.

```
$('#optionDiv').find("div#option_" + a).find("input#optionText_" + a)
            .attr(
                "name",
                "myField.optionList["
                + a + "].myFieldDescDataList["
                + secondSplit[2]
                + "].desc");
```

Comment: Try Ctrl + i or Shit + Ctrl + i.

Answer (score 0):

For Format you can use
CTRL + SHIFT + F

For correct indentation use
CTRL + I

[image]

If these two do not solve your issue,then you will have to go manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **eclipse-->preferences-->Java-->Code Style** to edit your Code style